# How interaction between users can be done using ARCore?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

How interaction between users can be done using ARCore. As can be seen from this video both the person on call can put objects `Arrows` on same screen which [is visible to both](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFhpAe10qnk).

But as I understood from ARCore code is that rendering on surface is done by camera itself, so how the remote side person is able to add objects to video which is visible to both?

Is some AR related information is exchanged and then both the side devices render objects based on that information?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with Unity's ARInterface, which is still in it's early stages so things are likely to change drastically (and hopefully get better): https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/experimental-ARInterface

I believe you'll want to check out their multiplayer example: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/experimental-ARInterface/tree/master/Assets/UnityARInterface/Examples/Multiplayer

Comment: Thanks nerk.... In multiplayer example, different devices focus on same object, like TANK example, both devices focus on same table. But my requirement is when both users are in different locations. As can be seen in this vide [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFhpAe10qnk ) video call is made but both users are at different locations. So how this can be achieved using ARCore. (Both user placing object on same scene and those objects are visible to both.

Comment: Checking their website, seems like they're developing the technology for it rather than writing a few lines of smart code. Some are APIs have it. Like chalk on vuforia

Answer (score 0):

> It's possible thanks to [ARCore Cloud Anchors](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/arcore-cloud-anchors/#0).

Creating a Hosted Anchor is not a rocket science. For that you need to configure the ARCore Session and enable support for Cloud Anchors (in the `MainActivity` class):

```
Config config = new Config(session);
config.setCloudAnchorMode(Config.CloudAnchorMode.ENABLED);
session.configure(config);
```

Then create the following new enum:

```
private enum AppAnchorState {
    NONE,
    HOSTING,
    HOSTED
}
@GuardedBy("singleTapAnchorLock")
private AppAnchorState appAnchorState = AppAnchorState.NONE;
```

And then modify two lines as follows:

```
Anchor newAnchor = session.hostCloudAnchor(hit.createAnchor());
setNewAnchor(newAnchor);

appAnchorState = AppAnchorState.HOSTING;
snackbarHelper.showMessage(this, "Now hosting anchor...");
```